# How to display open graph actions similar to like button in facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-javascript-sdk

When ever I open a Social Reader, it shows

```
<img src="friend img"> Your friend and 10 others Read this article
```

This is certainly not a Facebook's Like button. So, how can I achieve this kind of plugin! based upon graph actions??

Answer (score 0):

> So, how can I achieve this kind of plugin! based upon graph actions??

Store the information, which Facebook users have read the article, into your database – and then intersect them with the friends of the currently logged in user.

Comment: okay! if in case I just want the count!! Should I even need to store that? All I am thinking is that, there might be some JS which tracks all graph actions based on the "URL" of the article!!

Comment: You’d have to find that JS written by a third party, or write it yourself. The only direct mechanism Facebook provides are those embedded into the social plugins as the like button.